# php mail function error - Only last email address of my clientlist will be displayed in inbox

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am working to get more personalised with my clients by mail.
Everything works fine with the code but when i do some test mails, Only the last email address of my client list will be displayed in the inbox.

E.g. My client mailing list is 100+ email addresses and when I mail them,  all of them will see the mail address on the last line in my mailing list instead of theirs.

See
`<p>Dear '.$clientmail.', </p>`

and

```
$address = file('MUgWgJJE9m7FHh4TFrLHf6YzE.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($address as $clientmail) {
    $mail_sent = @mail($clientmail);
}
```

I'm working to fix this problem for a good few hours, but can't..
If someone can fix this that would be highly appreciated.

Here is full code to give you more insight.

```
<?php
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'on');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
//ob_end_flush();
while (@ob_end_flush());

// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

flush();

/// Now start the program output

$subject = 'subject here';
$headers = "From: mail <mail @mail.com>\n" . 
         "Reply-To: mail <mail @mail.com>\n" . 
         "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";

$address = file('MUgWgJJE9m7FHh4TFrLHf6YzE.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($address as $clientmail) {
    $mail_sent = @mail($clientmail);
}

$template = file_get_contents("template/template.png");

$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Dear '.$clientmail.', </p>
    <strong>rest of content</strong>
    <p>'.$template.'</p>
</body>
</html>
'; 

$emails = file('MUgWgJJE9m7FHh4TFrLHf6YzE.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$x = 1;
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $mail_sent = @mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f mail@mail.com');
    echo $mail_sent ? 
    $x . '. Mail send to: ' . $email . ' | ' . '<b><font color=green> Successfully Sended!</font><font color=lime> &check; </font></b>' . '<br/>' : 
    $x . '. Mail send to: ' . $email . ' | ' . '<b><font color=red> Error 02931: Contact To Fix Issue</font></b>' . '<br/>'; 
    $x++;

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: You need to do the token replacement inside your `foreach($address`... loop no? What does this line do: `$mail_sent = @mail($clientmail);` ? Why are you suppressing errors?

Comment: You're generating one message (i.e., in `$message`) and then sending that one message to each recipient. You need to take that part that sets `$message` and move it so that it's inside the loop, that way it changes on every iteration. (Not sure what your first foreach loop is meant to accomplish. Are you sending two messages to each recipient?)

Comment: Yeah, that first loop makes no sense at all!

Comment: Removed first loop.. excuse me about that.. Moved $message to second loop and got it working.. abit tired and dont know why i used a second loop for that.